# How do I split a string from a table field to populate multiple fields in another table?

Tags: string, sql-server-2008

I have a field in an import table with a model number and a model name that looks like this.

```
601F-2 Door
590 Door
690 Mechanical 2
611-2 Mechanical
611 Cosmetic(b4100000)
690 Sealed System(b4100000)
685-2 Sealed System(A#M2271174-P2273569)
```

I want to split this field into a new existing table with the first part of the field(delimited by ' ') into the key field, and the remaining data into a name/description field.

```
Models
 Model_No (nchar(10) PRIMARY KEY)
 Model_Name (nchar(30) NOT NULL)
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: what about last entry which have two spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Models (Model_No, Model_Name)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(import_field, ' ', 1), SUBSTRING(import_field, LOCATE(' ', import_field)+1)
   FROM import_table
```

It'll get data from `import_table` and insert it into `Models` table.

Comment: 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @DominicRomano It should be accessible from MySQL 5.0. If you've got older version, thing about updating.

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX for the second column doesn't work because there are model names with extra spaces in them. Use SUBSTRING(import_field, LOCATE(' ', import_field)+1) instead.

Comment: I really do appreciate the help, and your solution looks so eloquent, but my error in my post is that I am on SQL Server 2008, and SUBSTRING_INDEX doesn't work. Can you translate to SQL Server please. Thanks.

Comment: It was an error. Sorry Elon. Great code though. Much better than what I've seen in the books.